# How to clip Bitmap with a Path

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, overlay, clipping

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

[image]

As you can see the red lined thumbnail is partly clipped on the right side with a border.
This border separates the green lined thumbnail wich is clipped on both borders.
I could really use some example code on how i can achieve this.

As you can see the green thumb slightly overlays the red thumb though never overlaps on the top side where the / border passes. Basicly the images slide in next to each other.

The black box you see behind it is a simple png i dont have to use it if the effect can be achieved with some sort of Bitmap clipping. However i do not know how to do this.

What i am asking for is:

- How to clip the thumbnails so achieve the described effect above?
- Any ideas on how to clip the button like that?
- Any suggestions on how to do it differently?

I am really breaking my head over this and im lost.
Please help me stack overflow :)